# Excel mutual pairing

Tags: excel

How can I pair members of a list such that if the pair of member 'a' is member 'b' then the pair of 'b' is 'a', in MS Excel?

Ideally, the pairing randomizes at each calculation.

**Attempt:**

1) I have a list of names in a column, (column B).

2) I put the natural numbers up to the list length in column A:

```
=ROW(B2)-1
```

3) Random numbers in column C:

```
=RAND()
```

4) I ranked ordered the randoms in column D.

```
=RANK(C2, $C$2:$C$178)
```

Thus I have two orderings. The order of appearance in comumn A and a random order in D.

*However, for example, row by row the "pair of 11" does not have 11 as its pair, in turn. How can I achieve a mutual pairing? If 11 is paired with 27 I need 27 to be paired with 11 also.*

(I can then VLOOKUP to pull the names.)

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$178,2,0)
```

**EDIT:**

Bellow is my output. You can see that 'c' is the pair of 'a' but 'a' is **not** pair of 'c'. (The F column checks if someone is paired to themselves.)

[image: My Pairing]

So basicly in the output E column I am taking the name corresponding to the random rank ordering. I would like to acheve mutual pairs in some way.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? please give an example

Comment: I am trying to output the name of the pair. For example if 'a' is the pair of 'b' and 'b' is on row 2, I would like to output 'a', on row 2. Also, then 'b' needs to be the pair of 'a'. I think this is what you are asking, @Daghan.

Comment: Should I upload my failing notebook somewhere?

Comment: No its, fine. Edit your question with an uploaded picture of your desired output with numerical values.

Comment: You are trying to come up with a random permutation which consists of disjoint transpositions. Are there always an even number of items? That is possible, especially with VBA. Tangentially, the fact that Enigma permutations of the alphabet were permutations of that sort was the key theoretical weakness that the Allies were able to exploit in order to break it.

Comment: So you can have first pair of a with c and second with d? Similarly, c with a and c with d?

Comment: Yes, assume that they are always an even number. A random permutation that consists of discjoint transpositions may work. I don't know if it is necassary but my feeling is that it is sufficient. (I'm guessing that in such a permutation, if a -> b then b -> a, this is necassary and sufficient.) How can I do this in VBA, @JohnColeman?

Comment: Thank you, @NareshBhople. This would not work. I need a distinct mutual coupling of budies, e.g. a&b, b&a, c&d, d&c.

Comment: But the example screen shot in the question is showing a&c , d&a, c&d ?

Comment: @NareshBhople The example is currently showing "This is what I get, and it is wrong".  There is text explaining why it is wrong, but the post could be made clearer by adding an "and this is what it would look like if it was correct" image too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach. In your column E you have a permutation of the names. Keep this as an intermediate column. In this case it is `c,b,d,a`. Simply match `c` to `b` and `d` to `a`. `Index` and `Match` can be used to extract the pairings like this:

[image]

The crucial formula in `F2` is

```
=IF(MOD(MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$5,0),2) = 0,INDEX($E$2:$E$5,MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$5,0)-1),INDEX($E$2:$E$5,MATCH(B2,$E$2:$E$5,0)+1))
```

The formulas in columns D, E are exactly as you gave them.

Comment: This calculates noticably faster in my tests than Chronocidals answer. I feel it's orders of magnitude faster. Thank you.

Comment: Let me know if I should open a separate question. How can I select a miximaly non redundant set? Or how can ignore or delete the redundant cells now?

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean by "mixmaly non redundant set". Presumably you mean "minimally non redundant set", but I don't know what that means either. This approach uses intermediate columns, and I don't see any straightforward way to dispense with them (though there probably is by using array formulas, and you could also switch to VBA). You could always hide them.

Comment: I would like to get rid of the redundant entries or ignore them. This is, each couple appears twice. It appears in one order and then in the opposite order. I am going trough the used range in VBA. So I can use a tag in an additial column and use the value of the tag in a conditional in VBA. I just can't get the tag to tag only half of the list members. Basically, I concatenated the pairs in the next column (columnt G) and I am trying to manipulate it.

Comment: I'm going to ask in a separate question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to randomly pair up the numbers like this, you **need** to take into account what numbers have already been picked.  *Then*, you need to randomly select from the **remaining** numbers.

So, to do this, I am going to scrap your "Random Number" column, and calculate "Rank" directly.  To start with, we check if this item *already* has a pair.  All we will do is use `MATCH` to find if this entry already exists earlier in Column D, and (if so) use `INDEX` to find what number it has been paired up with:

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(A2, D$1:D1, 0))
```

<sup>All code, except the last example, will be written for Cell D2</sup>

If this entry has already been paired up, it will return an error.  Otherwise, it will return a match.  If no match was found, we need to pick one at random.  This condition is just an `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(A2, D$1:D1, 0)), <FIND_RANDOM_RANK>)
```

There are several ways to get the a Rank at Random, but I am going to use `AGGREGATE` and `RANDBETWEEN`.  We will create a list of the un-picked numbers in `AGGREGATE` (e.g. `{2, 3, 7, 8, 12}`), then use `RANDBETWEEN` to select a position at random (e.g. `RANDBETWEEN(1, 5)`, because there are 5 items to choose from).  Our list will be made of Row Numbers, so we will need to convert them to Sequence Numbers with `INDEX`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(A2, D$1:D1, 0)), INDEX(A:A, <FIND_RANDOM_ROW>))
```

Since our Row Number *are* numbers, so we can put them in order and pick the *k<sup>th</sup>* `SMALL`est

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, <NUMBER_LIST>, RANDBETWEEN(1, <NUMBER_OF_ITEMS>))
```

The Number of Items will be the total Number, minus how many items have already been paired.  The number of items already paired will be the number of items above us in the list, PLUS however many of those are paired with items further down.

```
AGGREGATE(15, 6, <NUMBER_LIST>, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A:A)-(Row()+COUNTIF(D$1:D1,">"&A2))))
```

In the Number List, we can use `#DIV0!` errors to mark items as Excluded.  We exclude them if they have already been paired up: either above us in the list, or paired to an item above us in the list.

```
ROW(A:A) / ((Row(A:A)>Row()) * (COUNTIF(D$1:D1,A:A)=0))
```

Now, before we stick everything together, we need to **limit our column sizes** in this part (which will work as an Array Formula).  If we try to calculate this for all 1048576 rows in the Worksheet, then not only would it take *ages*, but you would be matching against a lot of empty rows.

To do this, we can use `INDEX` and `COUNTA` to work out how many rows of record we have.  This means, for example, changing `A:A` to `A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))`.  If you have 10 rows of data, then this will go `A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))` → `A$1:INDEX(A:A,10)` → `A$1:A10`, which is 100,000 times less data to process!

```
ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))) / ((Row(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))>Row()) * (COUNTIF(D$1:D1,A:A)=0))
```

**Now**, we can put that all together, to get our final equation:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(A2, D$1:D1, 0)), INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))) / ((ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)))>ROW()) * (COUNTIF(D$1:D1,A:A)=0)), RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A:A)-(ROW()+COUNTIF(D$1:D1,">"&A2))))))
```

This will give us our Matched Rank.  All we need to do then is a quick `VLOOKUP` on Columns A and B to work out what the name is:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

<sup>*This* code is for Cell E2</sup>

(All-in-all, this code will be a lot more efficient if your list is of a fixed size, and you can then replace the `COUNTA(A:A)` and `A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))` bits with the correct numbers and cell references directly, such as `5` and `A$1:A$5`)